# CSRF Token Fails When Attempting To Serve Django App On A Subdomain

Tags: django

I am successfully configured two Django apps on these domains respectively:

http://omerselcuk.engineer

http://visions.omerselcuk.engineer

They both work well on GET requests, but while the first (main domain) works with POST requests, the second (subdomain) does not. I can verify I have included `{% csrf_token %}` correctly, because I cannot even log in to admin panel. (Admin panel is accessible but not loginable.)

They both accessible publicly and second Django app's DEBUG is on for you to test yourself if you want.

To clarify, when I serve second one on the main domain but in a different port, it works just as expected.

Answer (score 5):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/):

> In addition, for HTTPS requests, strict referer checking is done by
>   CsrfViewMiddleware. This means that even if a subdomain can set or
>   modify cookies on your domain, it can’t force a user to post to your
>   application since that request won’t come from your own exact domain.
>
> This also addresses a man-in-the-middle attack that’s possible under
>   HTTPS when using a session independent secret, due to the fact that
>   HTTP Set-Cookie headers are (unfortunately) accepted by clients even
>   when they are talking to a site under HTTPS. (Referer checking is not
>   done for HTTP requests because the presence of the Referer header
>   isn’t reliable enough under HTTP.)
>
> If the CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN setting is set, the referer is compared
>   against it. This setting supports subdomains. For example,
>   CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.example.com' will allow POST requests from
>   www.example.com and api.example.com. If the setting is not set, then
>   the referer must match the HTTP Host header.
>
> Expanding the accepted referers beyond the current host or cookie
>   domain can be done with the CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS setting.

The last two paragraphs are the important parts. You need to set `CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.omerselcuk.engineer'` or set [`CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have already done these, as `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["visions.omerselcuk.engineer"]` and `CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = "visions.omerselcuk.engineer"`. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Well, I got suspicious and changed these to `.omerselcuk.engineer` and it works like a charm. But, I did not understand why that happened. Can you guide me through that?

Comment: What if you're not working with subdomains but with any domain? e.g. your app is at `myapp.com` but there's also `domain.com` or `example.org` or `client12345.net`. How do you make CSRF work for these?

Comment: You can't make csrf work with *any* domain as that defeats the purpose of it. If it's a finite list, you add them to the trusted origins as stated above.